# Nifi - ConsumeKafka processor is unable to extract record header (type Long) correctly

Tags: apache-nifi, kafka-consumer-api

I have a Kafka topic that contains Avro records with custom Kafka headers.

I'm trying to extract those headers as flowFile attributes:
Processor: ConsumeKafka_2_6
-> Property: "Headers to Add as Attributes (Regex)"
-> Value: .*

In headers, I have values that contain information about the record. This includes timestamps etc as String, and one field is Scala's Long datatype.

For Strings the processor works as expected. But Long values are converted to some "random" ascii-characters, and i'm not able to convert those to original Long value for any means i can think of..

I'm not sure why this is happening OR how to solve this.. any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: Solved this problem with ExecuteScript processor / groovy script: byte[] bytes = value; long_value = new BigInteger(bytes).longValue();

Comment: Hi, can you please share your entire script? How exactly did you modify the headers? Thanks!